# Kendo UI JS grid editing cells won't work and gives no error

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I press any of the cells the cell get focused but I can't type anything in the field. I also get no console errors whatsoever. Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/DiscountPromotion/Get',
            dataType: "json",
        },
        update: {
            url: '/DiscountPromotion/Update',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        destroy: {
            url: '/DiscountPromotion/Delete',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        create: {
            url: '/DiscountPromotion/Add',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read") {
                return JSON.stringify({ discountPromotionDto: options });
            }
        },

    },
    pageSize: 10,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { type: "number" },
                Code: { type: "string" },
                StartDate: { type: "date" },
                EndDate: { type: "date" },
                MinimumCost: { type: "number" },
                MaximumCost: { type: "number" },
                Quantity: { type: "number" },
                CustomerId: { type: "number" },
                CountryCode: { type: "string" },
                Discount: { type: "number" },
                ModelName: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    }
});
$("#discountpromotiongrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: datasource,
    batch: true,
    toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
    height: 400,
    navigatable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    columns: [
    {
        field: "ModelName",
        title: "ModelName",
        editor: modelNameDropDown,
        template: "#=ModelName#",
        width: 150
    },
    {
        field: "Code",
        title: "PromotionCode",
        width: 150
    },
    {
        field: "StartDate",
        title: "StartDate",
        template: '#= kendo.toString(StartDate,"yyyy-MM-dd") #',
        width: 120
    },
    {
        field: "EndDate",
        title: "EndDate",
        template: '#= kendo.toString(EndDate,"yyyy-MM-dd") #',
        format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
        parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd"],
        width: 120
    },
    {
        field: "MinimumCost",
        title: "MinCost",
        width: 100
    },
    {
        field: "MaximumCost",
        title: "MaxCost",
        width: 100
    },
    {
        field: "Quantity",
        title: "Quantity",
        width: 80
    },
    {
        field: "CustomerId",
        title: "CustomerId",
        width: 80
    },
    {
        field: "CountryCode",
        title: "CountryCode",
        width: 40
    },
    {
        field: "Discount",
        title: "Discount",
        width: 40
    },
    {
        command: "destroy",
        title: "&nbsp;",
        width: 120
    }],
    editable: true
});



function modelNameDropDown(container, options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="ModelName" data-value-field="ModelName" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            optionLabel: "Select model...",
            dataSource: {
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/DiscountPromotion/GetModelNamesByCustomerId',
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

[image]

Please help! I have no clue what could be wrong.

Here is an image of my grid and when I have pressed a cell. There marker never shows up in the cell so I can't type anything. And this occurs on all of them!

Comment: could you make a fiddle or telerik dojo that reproduce your current situation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an edit command to your columns.

```
{
    command: ["edit", "destroy"],
    title: "&nbsp;",
    width: 120
}],
editable: "inline"
```